# How to run a .bat file in Go

Tags: go

I seem to cant figure out why I am having such a big problem trying to run a bat file in go.
My files look like this:

```
   cmd--
       |
       -----main.go
       |
       -----RUNNER.bat
```

I have been trying to run in main.go

```
    cmd := exec.Command("./RUNNER.bat")
    if err := cmd.Run(); err != nil{
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
```

and ill I get back is exit status 1. I know the .bat file is good because if I run it from a normal cmd it works perfectly fine

Comment: Windows paths in CMD won't  recognize `./`. Try removing that: `exec.Command("RUNNER.bat")`.

Comment: @tentative `exec: "RUNNER.bat": executable file not found in %PATH%`
thats what I get back when trying to run that

Comment: Then your working directory must not be where you expect it to be in `cmd`. Try checking the return value of this function https://golang.org/pkg/os/#Getwd and possibly try setting your [GOPATH](https://golang.org/doc/gopath_code)

Comment: @tentative I would want my go path set to directly the cmd folder?

Comment: Depends on if you need files in other folders later on. I'd recommend providing the Windows path instead, if your working directory is above `cmd` right now: `cmd\RUNNER.bat`.

Comment: Consider using [`filepath.Abs()`](https://golang.org/pkg/path/filepath/#Abs) to convert your path to an absolute one. (If you compare that path to what you expect it to be, a mismatch will let you know if your current working directory isn't the one you expect -- though logging `os.Getcwd()` would also have alerted you to that).

Comment: Did you try my answer to your previous question? (https://stackoverflow.com/a/66287180/6309)

Answer (score 3):

I would not exec the .bat directly, but rather a CMD which would in turn execute the `.bat` script.

```
 command :=exec.Command("CMD","/C",`c:\full\path\to\script.bat`)
```

As commented, use [`filepath.Abs()`](https://golang.org/pkg/path/filepath/#Abs) to get the absolute path. The resulting string for said path should use the system separator `\`.

Comment: Could you explain why it is better to use CMD to call the bat file instead of running it directly? For my use case it worked perfectly.

Comment: @Chevalric It spawns a subshell which better isolates (and waits for the program to close) instead of being embedded in the main Go thread.